# Retrieving an array of id's?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I'm having issues with the current code, actually I'm not sure if I'm going about the right way either way.

My current script (the total) uploads a photo and returns the id from the MySQL database. When the photo is selected, it's also been given tags. To associate these tags, I have chosen to have a table 'tagrefs' which simple combine tag_id with photo_id for later querying. The table 'tags' consists of tag_id and tag_name. The table 'photos' has tons of fields, the only relevant one being photo_id.

Currently, I pass the tags via POST.

```
      $tags = trim($_POST['tags']);
  $tags = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $tags);
  $tags = htmlspecialchars($tags);
  $tags = mysql_real_escape_string($tags);
  $tags = strip_tags($tags);
  $tags = explode(",", $tags);

$insert = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO tags (tag_name) VALUES (:tag)');
$insert->bindParam(':tag', $tag, PDO::PARAM_STR);
foreach ($tags as $tag) $insert->execute();


$select = $dbh->prepare('SELECT tag_id FROM tags WHERE tag_name = (:tag)');
$select->execute();
$result = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);
print("\n");
```

Up until $select it works perfectly. Tags are inserted, photo is uploaded. Peachy. Now I need to write something that will give me the tag_id of the tag_name s I just added, then I need to combine that with the photo_id and insert that into 'tagrefs'. The bottom $select is my failing attempt to retrieve said tag_id's that I just created by comparing them to the string the user POSTs. The manner I was thinking of is retrieving them, then creating a new array with the photo_id and the tag_id s and inserting the values into 'tagrefs'.

It all sounds overly complicated and there is probably a much better/safer way to do it but an hour of Googling has not helped.

Comment: If your tags are unique, why give them a tag ID at all? Why not just use the tag itself, and create a multi-column index on both columns in `tagrefs` table to ensure the same tag can't be associated with the same photo more than once? Then you'd never have to lookup those IDs, you could just refer to the tag.

Comment: @ithcy Mostly to save space and to save the tag association if they are ever corrected (spelling errors come to mind). If I save the tag name in the reference column and I edit the original tag, these changes will not be reflected in the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($tags as $tag) $insert->execute();
```

is incorrect. There's no `{}`, so all the foreach is doing is that one execute call, over and over. The rest of the code afterwards is NOT executed as part of the foreach. As such, you insert all of the tags, then when the loop is completed, you try to fetch the id of the LAST tag you inserted. Assuming this tag_id is an auto_increment primary key field, you should be using something like this:

```
foreach($tags as $tag) {
    $insert->execute();
    $tag_id = $insert->lastInsertId();
    ....
}
```

and not doing a dedicated select anyways.

Comment: Agree (and upvoted) this answer, but the original code has an additional problem. If the same tag_name is entered for two different photos, the tag_name will be entered twice in the tag table. You either need to check for the tag_name already being in the table (and retrieve the tag_id at the same time using a SELECT statement), or you can use the MySQL "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" syntax (with the tag_name field defined as UNIQUE and nothing as the UPDATE statement) to prevent this problem. The MySQL manual says lastInsertID() should work correctly in this case (I haven't tested).

Comment: @UltraOne The tag_name is unique in the db, it will not ever be in there twice. I simply haven't coded a line that catches it in PHP with a nice error message yet. 

Marc B, I will try your solution in a bit (:

Comment: foreach($tags as $tag) {
    $insert->execute();
    $tag_id = $dbh->lastInsertID();
 echo $tag_id."+".$photo_id."<br />";
 $sql = "INSERT INTO tagrefs (tag_id, photo_id) VALUES (:tag_id,:photo_id)";
 $q = $dbh->prepare($sql);
 $q->execute(array(':tag_id'=>$tag_id,            ':photo_id'=>$photo_id));
    }

This is now working fine. I substituted your $insert with $dbh. However, when I upload a new picture and give it the same tags, the tagrefs will all assign the new photo_id zeroes (as it is not returning inserted tags, they are already present). How do I work around this?